# jQuery validation plugin multiple remote issue. Is it me or bug?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using jQuery Validation plug-in in my two step registration form.

On "First Step" I'm checking username and email availability with remote function.

Here is the bug (or me!):

- If username exist in database and email is not, when I click "next" button the script letting me go to second step. (It shouldn't because username exist!)

but;

- If username not exist and email is exist in the database, It's stops me there and warns me email is exist. So it's working.
- If both username and email exist in the database, also stops me. So again working.

Here is code I'm using;

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <p>Page.</p>
    <form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return false;" action="" method="post" id="myform">

    <div id="stepusername">

            <p>This is step 1</p>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off"><br>

            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" autocomplete="off"><br>            

            <p><a class="btn btn-primary next">Go to step 2</a></p>  

    </div><!-- signup_one ends -->

    <div id="stepemail">

            <p>This is step 2</p>

            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password" autocomplete="off"><br>

            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="conf_password" name="conf_password" placeholder="password" autocomplete="off"><br>              

            <input class="btn btn-success next" type="submit" value="Finish">

    </div><!-- step2 ends -->

    </form>

    <div id="stepsuccess">

    <p>Show result here.</p>

    </div><!-- success ends -->


</div><!-- tab-content ends -->
```

**Java Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // jQuery.validate script, does client-side validation
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".next").click(function(){
            var form = $("#myform");
            form.validate({
                errorElement: 'div',
                errorClass: 'formerror',
                highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass("has-error");
                },
                unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass("has-error");
                },
                rules: {
                    username: {
                        required: true,
                        remote: { 
                        url: "check-username.php",
                        async: false,
                        type: "post", }
                    },                                                          
                    password : {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    conf_password : {
                        required: true,
                        equalTo: '#password',
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        remote: { 
                        url: "check-email.php",
                        async: false,
                        type: "post", }
                    },

                },

                messages: {
                    username: {
                        required: "Username required",
                        remote: "Taken username.",
                    },                                          
                    password : {
                        required: "Password required",
                    },
                    conf_password : {
                        required: "Password required",
                        equalTo: "Password don't match",
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: "Email required",
                        remote: "Taken email.",
                    },                          

                }

            });

            if (form.valid() === true){
                if ($('#stepusername').is(":visible")){
                    current_fs = $('#stepusername');
                    next_fs = $('#stepemail');
                }else if($('#stepemail').is(":visible")){
                    current_fs = $('#stepemail');
                    next_fs = $('#stepsuccess');
                }

                next_fs.show(); 
                current_fs.hide();
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

*Update:*

**check-username.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
try {
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users', 'root', '');
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {  
     echo $e->getMessage(); 
     die(); 
}

$request = $_REQUEST['username'];
$query = $handler->query("SELECT * from usertable WHERE username='$request'");
$results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(empty($request)) {
    echo 'false' ;
}else {

if ($results == 0) {
$valid = 'true';
}
else {
$valid = 'false';
 }

echo $valid ;
}
?>
```

**check-email.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
try {
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users', 'root', '');
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {  
     echo $e->getMessage(); 
     die(); 
}

$request = $_REQUEST['email'];
$query = $handler->query("SELECT * from usertable WHERE email='$request'");
$results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(empty($request)) {
    echo 'false' ;
}else {

if ($results == 0) {
$valid = 'true';
}
else {
$valid = 'false';
 }

echo $valid ;
}
?>
```

Also jsFiddle if you like to see: http://jsfiddle.net/noptpece/

Comment: Have you ever considered that your `check-username.php` doenst work?

Comment: @TomDoodler It actually does work. When I put taken username and available email, I click "next" It shows "Taken username" message but anyway lead me to next step. But other conditions I wrote in my message, doesn't let me go to next step.

Comment: Which, again, imply in what @TomDoodler said, your `php` algorithm might be failing to that *specific* verification. Please consider posting it with your question.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale, @Tom Doodler, gentlemen you are right. I updated my post. I also added `check-email.php` for your considerations.

Comment: @Lukasz I don't know much about that validation plugin you're using, but I have a suggestion. Try to change "async" from `username` rule to `true`. It might being bypassed because it's verifying your rules synchronously (each at a time).

Comment: @AedixRhinedale, this time doesn't check username at all. Anyway it actually not being bypassing. Kind of "half bypassing" because it goes next even thought tells me "username is taken"

Comment: Wait. Let's refactor your logic. You're searching for already supplied usernames and emails so it won't be duplicated into your database right? They must be unique. Can a user input an already taken username but not an already taken email and vice versa? Because if **not**, then it's no use doing both checkings. Just one of them, once succeeded, should lead your script to a "Data Already Taken" alert or anything like it.

Comment: That part of your code `current_fs = $('#stepusername'); next_fs = $('#stepemail');` seems to tell your JS to proceed to email checking after username checking regardless if it fails or not, even with your PHP script working as expected.

Comment: There are three contitions but only two of them working for me. They are:      _1- If username not exist and email is exist in the database, It's stops me there and warns me email is exist. So it's working._
     _2- If both username and email exist in the database, also stops me. So again working._
But third condition fails which is: _3- If username exist in database and email is not, when I click "next" button the script letting me go to second step. (It shouldn't because username exist!)_

Comment: Can you change the order of your rules and put `username` to be checked the last?

Comment: @AedixRhinedale, it's my bad there in the code. `#stepusername` `div`'s both contains username and email `input`s and in `#stepemail` `div` there is password `input`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $handler->query("SELECT * from usertable WHERE username='$request'");
```

This line doesnt look, if a user exists, whos name equals the content of `$request`, it looks up if the user with the **name** "$request" exists, the same with the e-mail.

String composing in PHP works differently, you should write

```
$query = $handler->query("SELECT * from usertable WHERE username=".$request);
```

Also you should never ever use a MySQL query like this, because its the easiest thing of the world to inject SQL code and destroy your whole database.

Comment: I suggest you include the *correct way* also, where OP should bind parameters to the query string instead of calling vars inside it. It would be constructive.

Comment: I googled a few minutes but i couldnt find it and I dont have the possibility to look up in my own code atm, so i suggest you try to find it on your own, the keywords are `PDO` and `injection`, I hope I could help you. It works the way you do it, I just wouldnt publish it that way, for debugging and developement its more comfortable

Comment: Pls tell me if It fixed your problem

Comment: I changed to `$requestuser = $_REQUEST['username'];` and `$query = $handler->query("SELECT * from usertablo WHERE username='.$requestuser'");` but everything is still same.

Comment: Why should it be different, you've just changed the name of the variable, not the error I mentioned in my answer

Comment: I made my code `$requestuser = $_REQUEST['username'];
$query = $handler->query("SELECT * from usertable WHERE username=".$requestuser);` right now.  `check-username.php` doesn't work anymore. It should simply give me the `echo` `true` or `false` so javascript can understand. right now it gives me error. I think problem was somewhere else. because it was working before. Would you like to create a `check-username.php` only written inside `false` and `check-email.php` written inside `true` and try codes on your localhost for example? It will say you username taken but still lets you go.

Comment: Wouldn't work unless he recreates your database too.

Comment: The idea is `check-username.php?username=username` `echo` `true` or `false`. If you create an empty `check-username.php` and only write `false` inside, `check-username.php?username=username` also will say `false` to you. So it can work for understanding the issue.